# How to grant admin priviledges to any user?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'm trying to send this iq...

```
<iq to="localhost" type="get">
        <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node="all users"/>
</iq>
```

...to be able to retrieve all the users from the server, but I can only get a response **if the sender is the admin**.

If it's a **normal user** I get **"Denied by ACL"** error

How can I be able to get a response from the server to any user on the server.

I've also tried to make the admin user to be anyone in the **ejabberd.yml** but I couldn't achieve it.

Is there any way to make this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set in ejabberd.yml configuration file like that-

```
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin": "localhost"   
      - "user1": "localhost"
      - "user2": "localhost"

  ##
```

Comment: But if you have 150 users and every day new users are being registered that's not right..

Comment: why you are making too  users as admin? every registered can not be admin.Any registered user can execute all admin commands what about security?

Answer (score 0):

Method1: Modify **acl** & add set of users to the list.

```
acl:
  admin:
    user:
     - "admin": "localhost"
```

Method2: Modify **access rules** to grant access to all users.

```
access:
    configure:
        admin: allow
        all: allow
```

Note: I would not recommend method2 to be used in production.